# Angular - Lazy loading an entire page from CMS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to build an angular app that is driven by the CaaS/CMS known as Prismic.io.

Phase one of this project will be a straight forward content-silo (CMS-managed), and phase two will add on more complex web app components. Knowing this, I've decided that Angular would be my best bet, but I'm struggling to think of a good solution to have all of the content lazy-loaded from the Prismic API.

One solution I've decided to explore would be to have a standardized $scope variable, let's call it `$scope.loaded`. Each controller will do what it must to query my Prismic service for its respective content, and once it's completed, it would set `$scope.loaded = true`.

The part I'm stuck on with this approach is how exactly to display the page while all of these components are loading. The easiest way would be to include `ng-if` directives that reference this `loaded` value, but I feel like there'd be a massive flash of unstyled content. And yes I could use spinners, but the idea of having 90% of the page covered in spinners seems chintzy.

Then I got to wondering: what if I pull up a loading screen for the app until all controllers' `$scope.loaded` values are truthy? In that case, how would I know which controllers are currently active on the page and reference their respective scopes?

(If you have comments about why this approach is bad, I'd love to hear them as replies rather than answers. I imagine this could create too many http request, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options here:

Have you looked at `ngCloak` to see if will help you here with the flicker problem? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.

If you're using jquery, you could have a global spinner that works on concurrent ajax requests http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/.

Or have a look at something like this global angular spinner https://github.com/monterail/angular-global-spinner/tree/master/src.

If none of these work, you could always create an array on the root scope where each controller/directive registers itself and sets its loading flag. Then add a watch to that variable to see when all components in that array are finished loading.